# web сервис на spring boot не подключается к elasticsearch через докер контейнеры

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, elasticsearch

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть web сервис на spring boot, который общается с elasticsearch. Elasticsearch я запускаю в контейнере docker. Если я запускаю web сервис на локальной машине, то все работает отлично, но как только я пытаюсь запустить web сервис в контейнере возникают ошибки

Логи из docker logs name_container

```
2023-06-25 17:54:41.964  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.s.SpringElasticProjectApplication    : Starting SpringElasticProjectApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.7 on fc2e6b22b78a with PID 1 (/app/*.jar started by root in /app)
2023-06-25 17:54:41.969  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.s.SpringElasticProjectApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-25 17:54:42.686  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Elasticsearch repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-25 17:54:48.142  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5448 ms. Found 2 Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
2023-06-25 17:54:48.381  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Elasticsearch repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-25 17:54:48.384  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 Reactive Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
2023-06-25 17:54:49.221  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-06-25 17:54:49.233  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-25 17:54:49.234  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2023-06-25 17:54:49.324  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-25 17:54:49.324  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7273 ms
2023-06-25 17:54:50.422  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'catalogImportService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/*.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/example/springelasticproject/service/CatalogImportService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.example.springelasticproject.repository.ProductRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on SpringElasticProjectApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; nested: ExecutionException[java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; nested: ConnectException[Connection refused];
2023-06-25 17:54:50.427  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-06-25 17:54:50.447  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-25 17:54:50.489 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'catalogImportService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/*.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/example/springelasticproject/service/CatalogImportService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.example.springelasticproject.repository.ProductRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on SpringElasticProjectApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; nested: ExecutionException[java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; nested: ConnectException[Connection refused];
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
    at com.example.springelasticproject.SpringElasticProjectApplication.main(SpringElasticProjectApplication.java:12) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[*.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[*.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[*.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[*.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.example.springelasticproject.repository.ProductRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on SpringElasticProjectApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; nested: ExecutionException[java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; nested: ConnectException[Connection refused];
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; nested: ExecutionException[java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; nested: ConnectException[Connection refused];
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:579) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:579) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:544) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:74) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:325) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; nested: ExecutionException[java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; nested: ConnectException[Connection refused];
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:601) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:584) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.doExists(RestIndexTemplate.java:106) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractIndexTemplate.exists(AbstractIndexTemplate.java:130) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:87) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2695) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.4.jar!/:7.17.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.4.jar!/:7.17.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2154) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.4.jar!/:7.17.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists(IndicesClient.java:1279) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.4.jar!/:7.17.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.lambda$doExists$2(RestIndexTemplate.java:106) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:582) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.getValue(BaseFuture.java:257) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.4.jar!/:7.17.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:244) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.4.jar!/:7.17.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:75) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.4.jar!/:7.17.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2692) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.4.jar!/:7.17.4]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar!/:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar!/:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar!/:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar!/:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar!/:4.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/.
RUN mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/target/*.jar /app/*.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/*.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  b-elastic:
    image: elasticsearch:7.4.2
    container_name: b-elastic
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms750m -Xmx750m
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
    volumes:
      - ./:/project
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - elastic

  web-server:
    image: client:0.0.1
    container_name: web-server
    build:
      context: ./ElasticService
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - b-elastic
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT= 8080
      - TZ=Europe/Moscow
      - LOG_MODE=dev
      - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NODES=b-elastic:9200
    networks:
      - elastic


networks:
    elastic:
      external: true
      driver: bridge
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-elastic-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-elastic-project</name>
    <description>spring-elastic-project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверяли ли вы сам контейнер Эластика? Мне кажется, что `Connection refused` вы ловите именно из-за ошибки при запуске контейнера. Попробуйте добавить памяти `- ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx2G` и при запуске посмотрите на состояние контейнера.

Также обратите внимание, что даже явно указанное условие

```
depends_on:
  - b-elastic
```

не означает ожидания состояния "готовности" контейнера. В документации прямо [указано](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on), что

> There are several things to be aware of when using depends_on:
>
> - `depends_on` **does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web** - only until they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see Controlling startup order for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.
> - The `depends_on` option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a version 3 Compose file.

Поэтому если в вашем случае веб-приложение запускается до готовности Эластика обслуживать входящие запросы, то вам необходимо либо прописать явный перезапуск при ошибке (простое решение в лоб)

```
  web-server:
    restart: on-failure:5
```

либо использовать условие `service_healthy`.
Это вы дописываете в описание Эластик-контейнера:

```
healthcheck:
  test: curl -u elastic:elastic -s -f elasticsearch:9200/_cat/health >/dev/null || exit 1
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 5
```

А раздел `depends_on` приложения изменяете так:

```
depends_on:
  b-elastic:
    condition: service_healthy
```